# Moving old VS 2010 projects to VS 2017

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2017

I've searched for the specifics I'm looking for but not finding an exact match here.

I currently have a Windows 7 laptop with Visual Studio 2010 Professional. I am purchasing a new laptop with Windows 10 and am considering also purchasing Visual Studio 2017 Pro for the new laptop. I would like to copy my VS 2010 projects to the new laptop and convert them to VS 2017 projects. After converted, the projects do NOT have to remain compatible with VS 2010. As long as I can open the projects in VS 2017, edit code, and re-compile all in VS 2017 I'm happy.

90% of my projects are VB Winforms. But I have a few ASP.NET (VB) projects as well. Most are .NET Framework 4.0+, but may have a few old v3.5 maybe even v2.0.

It's mostly the more recent projects I care to actively work with. If I can't migrate an old project to VS 2017, I will most likely create a VM out of my current Win7 laptop and go back to it occasionally for the very old projects.

To add another factor here, I also heavily use DevExpress (Winforms and ASP.NET) controls on almost all of my projects. So I am planning on upgrading my version of DevExpress as well to be compatible with VS 2017.

Is this a straight forward migration? Any pitfalls to have serious concerns about here? Anyone who has gone thru this and can give some advice would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK when you open a VS2010 project in VS2017, auto migration will popup for you and VS will do all the code migration.

Comment: The best thing to do is just *try it* and see what happens. You could always download free VS 2017 Community Edition if you just want to try it out real quick, depending on the licensing restrictions.

Comment: You can install VS2017 community edition side by side with VS2010 on your existing laptop, and open up copies of your project to test the migration.

Comment: You missed too many VS releases in between, so you have to use the guides for VS2010->2012->2013->2015->2017 combined. Like others commented, try the automatic migration and fix the issues one by one.